# How to auto-populate form fields using vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm developing a web application where I want to populate some field if I type computer_number I want to populate staff_old_name field that will select from staffs table.

This is what I've tried:

**Template**

```
    <div>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Computer Number</th>
            <th>Old Name</th>
            <th>New Name</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(staff, index) in staffs">
            <td>
              <span v-if="staff.editmode"><input class="form-control" v-model="staff.computer_number"/></span>
              <span v-else>{{staff.computer_number}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span v-if="staff.editmode"><input class="form-control" v-model="staff.old_name"/></span>
              <span v-else>{{staff.old_name}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span v-if="staff.editmode"><input class="form-control" v-model="staff.new_name"/></span>
              <span v-else>{{staff.new_name}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span v-if="staff.editmode"><input class="form-control" v-model="staff.remarks"/></span>
              <span v-else>{{staff.remarks}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span v-if="!staff.editmode"><button class="btn btn-info" type="button" @click="edit(staff)">Edit</button></span>
              <span v-else><button class="btn btn-success" type="button" @click="save(staff)">Save</button></span>
              <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="remove(index)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="box-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" @click="cloneLast">Add Row</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                staffs: [],
                data_results: []
            }


       },
       computed:{
        autoComplete(){
           this.data_results = [];
           if(this.computer_number.length > 2){
            axios.get('/api/staffs/autocomplete',{params: {computer_number: this.computer_number}}).then(response => {
               console.log(response);
             this.data_results = response.data;
            });
           }
          }
       },
       methods: {
         edit :function(obj){
           this.$set(obj, 'editmode', true);
         },
         save : function(obj){
           this.$set(obj, 'editmode', false);
         },
         remove: function(obj){
            this.staffs.splice(obj,1);
         },
         cloneLast:function(obj){
           //var lastObj = this.staffs[this.staffs.length-1];
           //lastObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lastObj));
           obj.editmode = true;
           this.staffs.push(obj);
         },

       },
       created() {
            axios.get('/staff-names')
                 .then(response => this.staffs = response.data);
        },
    }
```

when I type the computer number I want the staff_old_name field populated base on staff name which is stored in staffs table.

[image: Change Staff Name]

Comment: Have you considered using something like https://github.com/tecbeast42/autocomplete-vue as your entry box for the computer number?

Comment: Also, is this for an asset tracking system where computers are allocated to staff? It seems like your approach to this is a little bit convoluted - you've designed for the specific task/action rather than the object edit.  Nothing wrong with that if it's an explicit requirement, but it looks like what you are really doing is an edit (ReST PATCH) on a 'computer', where you wish to change the allocated user.

Generally this would be approached through a "Computers" view, and the edit would be a change to the 'Allocated to Staff Member" field using a dropdown list or autocomplete.

Comment: This is a payroll system- computer_number(staff_id) there is an existing system designed with msaccess. I'm trying to change it to web based.